# Problem with diacritics and mb_substr

Tags: php, unicode, substr, multibyte

I am slicing unicode string with diacritics using `mb_substr` function but it works as I would use simple `substr` function. It splits unicode characters in half displaying question marked diamond.

E.g.

```
echo mb_substr('ááááá', 0, 5); //Displays áá�
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same problem if I don't specify the encoding as the last parameter to [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr) : it defaults, at least on my server, to `ISO-8859-1`.

But, if I set the encoding properly, to `UTF-8`, it works OK :

```
echo mb_substr('ááááá', 0, 5, 'UTF-8');
```

Gets the right display in the browser :

```
ááááá
```

See [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr) *(quoting, emphasis mine)* :

```
string mb_substr  ( string $str  , int $start  [, 
    int $length  [, string $encoding  ]] )
```

> The `encoding` parameter is
>   the character encoding. **If it is
>   omitted, the internal character
>   encoding value will be used**.

Comment: Internal character encoding may be changed in php.ini (even via ini_set() if you can't change it system-wide). I think that's a saner option (and would shoot idiot who chose single-byte default encoding for dedicated multi-byte functions).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the above answers helped me too. Beside setting `php.ini` or using [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), it may also help to use `mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');` (`utf-8` may be replaced at your choice) for setting permanent encoding for multibyte functions.